# Python class taking in only two arguments?

Tags: python, function, class, import

So I have a Python class named `Player()` that takes in a total of 20 arguments for a simple combat algorithm. Problem is, when I import `Player()` and the combat function into a main file, and have imported everything correctly, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Thomas\Desktop\Paradisium\main_draft.py", line 53, in <module>
     combat(player1,player2)
TypeError: __init__() missing 18 required positional arguments: 'speed', 'agility', 'endurance',           'hitpoints', 'HPregen', 'EPregen', 'originalHP', 'originalEP', 'originalMP', 'MP', 'MGKregen',  'MGKdefence', 'MGKattack', 'debuff', 'buff', 'setType', 'weapon', and 'name'
```

As you can see, it's importing correctly and grabbing the `Player()` class, for some reason it's only taking in two of the twenty variables that are defined here:

```
player1=Player(90,20,50,90,20,1000,.03,1,1000,20,20,20,1,90,100,2,2,3,None,"Somerled Murdoch")
```

I don't know if I'm importing wrong or something like that, and I'm pretty sure there is no limit to variables in a class.

Edit, here's the code:

The `Player()` class:

```
class Player (object):
def __init__(self, physicalAttack, defence, speed, agility, endurance, hitpoints, HPregen, EPregen, originalHP, originalEP, originalMP, MP, MGKregen, MGKdefence, MGKattack,
             debuff, buff, setType, weapon, name):
```

The `combat()` function:

```
def combat(player1,player2):
```

The lines where they are being imported into the main file:

```
import combatAlgorithmDraft
Player=combatAlgorithmDraft.Player
combat=combatAlgorithmDraft.Player
```

The lines where they are being called in the main file:

```
    player1=Player(90,20,50,90,20,1000,.03,1,1000,20,20,20,1,90,100,2,2,3,None,"Somerled Murdoch")
    player2=Player(60,70,60,50,20,1100,.01,1,1100,20,0,0,0,60,0,2,2,0,0,"The Black Knight")
    combat(player1,player2)
```

Comment: Posting the code that's causing the error might be useful.

Comment: The traceback shows you're calling `combat(player1, player2)`. It's the `combat` class that expects 18 more arguments.

Comment: Combat is a function that only takes in two arguments. And I will post the whole code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
combat=combatAlgorithmDraft.Player
```

Did you mean to do this?

```
combat=combatAlgorithmDraft.combat
```

---

In any case, the conventional way to import things from other modules into the current namespace is

```
from combatAlgorithmDraft import Player, combat
```

Comment: You should be hearing the echoing smack of my facepalm soon.